# Why does Lucilla have senator Gracchus meet with Maximus if she overheard Commodus' order to have every senator followed?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, gladiator

In *Gladiator*, Lucilla overhears Commodus' discussion with senator Falco where Commodus orders Falco to have every senator followed. Knowing this, why does she risk having senator Gracchus meet with Maximus? She risks having herself and the entire plot discovered by Commodus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no answer which can be confirmed or denied in official capacity, but the "reality" is along the lines of "how else can you effectively stage a coup in an era where there is only verbal or written communication when no one can be trusted *not* to be in the emperor's pocket, other than having the principal players meet and build trust in person?"

Gracchus invokes that his presence is evidence Maximus can trust him and his voice is the voice of the senate. Maximus suggests that if he is freed and can reach his army in Ostia, they can return to take Rome. Gracchus is leery of trading one dictatorship for another. Maximus confides he will return Rome to the senate as it was the dying wish of Marcus Aurelius.

This is simply a nod towards the gravity of the situation, that the risk associated in the direct meeting is outweighed by the merit of the deed. Any other interpretation would mean assigning the role of "foolish naive woman" to Lucilla, and at no other point is she portrayed in this manner, especially with her life, the life of her son, and the fate of the empire in the balance.

A less satisfactory answer may be that this "risk" she takes is an example of a plot hole in a mega blockbuster film, and it would not be the first nor probably the last. This film is not a depiction of historical events, and no official answer can be extrapolated from the script other than to interpret the context of the meeting - that being that things are rapidly snowballing into a much worse place than they already are, so much so that Gracchus and by all signs the senate as a whole are willing to take a calculated risk.